# customize output of command "openssl dgst -hmac"

Tags: hashing, openssl

I want to compute the HMAC of file A.txt and put it into file A_hmac.txt.
I use openss library, now I have:

```
openssl dgst -hmac "myHmacKey" -out A_hmac.txt A.txt
```

The output, inside A_hmac.txt, is:

```
HMAC-SHA256(A.txt)= 5aaee07459e341752...
```

How do I manage to have as output only:

```
5aaee07459e341752...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though, Not an OpenSSL solution, In Linux;

`openssl dgst -hmac "myHmacKey"  output.txt`

outputs

```
HMAC-SHA256(output.txt)= 3bcf4e453c9b8008035e7f5e0ea84f092f795fc602bb3adccfde0f916dd565b2
```

The using the `cut` on the space char

```
openssl dgst -hmac "myHmacKey"  output.txt  | rev | cut   -d' ' -f1 | rev > myHmacKey
```

Then `cat myHmacKey` outputs

`3bcf4e453c9b8008035e7f5e0ea84f092f795fc602bb3adccfde0f916dd565b2`

Comment: Thanks, this will work for me because my file has no space in their name.
However, I will keep my question alive in order to cover spaced names, just for academy.

Comment: The original answer, check the history, was not considering the space. Later I've thought that the filenames can contain spaces so I've updated the answer to deal with the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can first output as binary, then process with `xxd`, and finally redirect the output to your file.

```
openssl dgst -hmac "myHmacKey" -binary A.txt | xxd -p -c0 > A_hmac.txt
```